# Check if date range equals today and copy values below the date range to a new cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple horizontal date ranges, and I need to see if one of them = today, and if so copy the cells values beneath the date and paste them into a new cell.

[image: My table]

I managed to do 1 by 1 and multiple copy pastes.

```
Sub copyModes()

If Range("R29") = Date Then
    Range("R30:R34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P37:P41").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If Range("U29") = Date Then
    Range("U30:U34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P37:P41").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If Range("S29") = Date Then
    Range("S30:S34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P37:P41").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If Range("T29") = Date Then
    Range("T30:T34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P37:P41").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If Range("V29") = Date Then
    Range("V30:V34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P37:P41").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use generic sub like this:

```
Sub CheckRangeAndCopy(rng As Range)
    If rng.value = Date Then
        rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(5, 1).Copy Range("P37:P41")
    End If
End Sub
```

And then call it:

```
CheckRangeAndCopy Range("T29")
CheckRangeAndCopy Range("V29")
' and so on
```